# Child's event is not fired when parent's HTML is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, bind

Here's an example http://jsbin.com/ukoqud/3/edit

If you click on a red box, you'll get an alert.

If you click on a link, everything in a blue box will be replaced with just a red box. Link will disappear and if you click on a red box then, you'll get no alert.

1. Why this happens?
2. Is it related to innerHTML?
3. Does it work the same way in all browsers?

Here's one more example http://jsbin.com/ukoqud/1/edit In this one you'll get an alert after clicking on a link. Things happen in a quite similar way, but result is different.

I would like to understand the reason, there's no need to fix my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `$(".red")`, it returns a collection of DOM elements that exist at that moment. So `$(".red").click(function...)` just binds a handler to the click event on those elements. If you later create new elements with the same class, they weren't in this collection, so they don't have the handler bound to them.  jQuery doesn't watch the DOM for changes and update the handlers dynamically -- the bindings are just on the elements you matched at the time you called `click()`.

You either need to bind the handler again after adding the new HTML, or use *delegation* with `.on()`:

```
$(".blue").on("click", ".red", function(){
    alert('click on a red box detected');
});
```

This works by binding a handler to `$(".blue")`, which doesn't change dynamically. The handler checks whether the element you clicked on matches the ".red" selector, so it's able to handle dynamically-added elements without requiring rebinding.

I think the reason why it works in your second example is because the red block isn't inside the blue box to start. When you move it inside, jQuery reuses the same DOM elements, so the bindings go along with it.  In the first example, the red box starts out inside the blue box. When you do `$('.red').parent().html(...)`, the first thing it does is empty `$('.red').parent()` (the blue box), so the original red element is removed from the DOM, and its bindings are lost.

Comment: `f` is missing in `unction`

Comment: _elements you add dynamically later don't have any handlers bound to them_ - not clear for me. Describe please in depth, why this happens

Comment: the second example also uses `$(".red")`, but alert works. It's also replaced.

Comment: thanks @Barmer, but your answer doesn't describe why alert works in the second example.

Comment: I've added an explanation of the difference. It's kind of tricky, I hope it's understandable.

Answer (score 1):

We need to understand how setting html of an element works. Then you will figure out your answer yourself.

Take a look at this bin [Updated Bin](http://jsbin.com/ukoqud/18/edit)

- When we set HTML of an element, it first removes all the elements inside it.
- Those elements are not removed from memory depending upon whether they are garbage collected or not.
- If any of the child is having a reference, then that particular child won't be garbage collected.
- In your case, we are having a reference to red element so it is still present in memory but not a part of document.
- When we say blue.html(red) in my example, red element becomes a part of document again but this time there won't be any handlers on it So your click does not work.

While in your example2,

- red element is always a part of document hence no handlers were lost when red element is moved inside blue element.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

because when u click the link, you delete everything on screen and  create everything from a scratch and event binding goes away. so you should use this

```
 $(".blue").on("click", ".red", function(){
  alert('');
 });
```

this way, binding is done differently. it doesnt bind it statically

Comment: Same thing happens in the second example, but alert works for it.